# Multiple Apache Felix instances

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix

Currently working on a requirement to use multiple Apache Felix instances to serve different routes of a single web application.

Essentially, we'd like the first instance to process all search requests such as ~/search and a second instance to process everything else.

Firstly, I can't find many examples of this approach so I'm unsure if it's a good idea to begin with or if there is a better approach.

Secondly, where is the best place to handle the URL mapping?

Thank you in advance

**MORE INFO:**

There is an existing Felix web application which we do not want to modify. The search functionality of the website is being updated and is no longer interacting with the existing application. Instead, it's using a Solr index so the team would like to deploy an additional Felix instance as a proxy to Solr which also wraps some additional logic. I'm not 100% sure if this is an ideal solution which is why I'm curious if anyone has encountered/solved a similar problem.

Comment: Can you explain why you are considering this? Are you trying to balance the load? Or?!

Comment: I agree with @MarcelOffermans. You seem to have settled on a solution before analysing the requirements. It's very unlikely that you *really* need to have multiple Felix instances within the same process.

Comment: Yes I agree with you both - have added some additional information.